# Check if app has a notfication using private frameworks?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, libstatusbar

I'm writing a mobilesubstrate tweak for jailbroken devices that displays an icon in the statusbar if a defined app has a notification using [libstatusbar](https://github.com/phoenix3200/libstatusbar)

I'm having trouble locating where iOS keeps this notification info for each app. Could anyone point me in the right direction/framework?

I don't intend on submitting this to Apple, again it's for jailbroken devices.

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are two notifications which looks similar, but internally goes through different execution routes: local notification and remote push notifications.

I don't have exact answer. Couple of ideas, direction, where I would look for:

API's in private framework **SpringboardServices**

- Objective C SBSPushStore class
- Bunch of C API's SBSPush*

There is **ApplePushService** private framework. I believe it provides a connection through which remote notifications are received.

Also, there is a **BulletinBoardService**. I believe this one is related to showing the list of notifications. My guess, that it may store notifications.

Comment: I'd give a close look at all the BulletinBoard stuff, that's the codename for the Notification Center... And because the NC shows a list of notifications, it must have it saved somewhere ;)

Comment: @Victor Thanks. I couldn't find exactly what I needed but it was close. I was looking for at least an integer to show & remove my image from the statusbar. I can only dismiss my image when the app is loaded. That's about the only way I could tell if the user knew they had notifications and checked.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the file system I found my answer. To get application notification count for a givin app. Check the plist located at: /var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/applicationState.plist>com.app.identifier>SBApplicationBadgeKey

Comment: How to find this plist? Where to download this framework? Can you please share the complete step by step answer. Thanks