# How to get notification badge number from one app to another ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, badge

I have an app with a `tableView` which have the entries with names **whatsapp, messenger, slack** etc. Now take **Whatsapp** for example when you tap on it it'll open whatspp via deep linking.
I want to show notifications sum, which user has received on his whatsapp, onto my app. After searching around I came to knew that this is not possible to get push notifications of one app to another it's a server to server thing and many other explanations.
But my question is if notifications have been received on whatsapp can I get the badge number and sum it and show it in my app? This screenshot will show more:
[image]

So the `12` is coming from whatsapp as a sum of total unread messages you can say. So how to achieve that?

**UPDATE**
I found these links which says that it might be possible.
[How to catch all push notifications from other apps on iOS using private frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334153/how-to-catch-all-push-notifications-from-other-apps-on-ios-using-private-framewo)
[How can I receive push notifications of an other app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291925/how-can-i-receive-push-notifications-of-an-other-app)

Comment: No, since that information is outside of your app's sandbox and inside the Whatsapp sandbox.  You would need to communicate with each messaging service via an API if they have one.

Comment: @Paulw11 this app is doing it: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/im+-instant-messenger/id285688934?mt=8 and they also have whatsapp integrated. And whatsapp has no API as far as I've searched.

Comment: That app doesn't do anything with Whatsapp. It mentions Beep as being "whatsapp-like".  It looks like that App just implements all of the various client protocols.  It also seems to have some sort of server involved since you can get your chat history at http://plus.im  Personally I would be very wary about using something like this they may be holding your credentials on their server.  They claim to have "the most secure chat app" - Time and time again claims like this have bee shown to be untrue.  Regardless, they definitely aren't accessing the information from the other app on device

Comment: I see that IM+ says on their facebook page that they now work with Whatsapp, so they may have reverse engineered the protocol.  The Whatsapp uris you linked to let you do what they say; send messages, share items.

Comment: @Paulw11 hmmm... may be you're right! we can only deep link then! Did see anything that might give me what I'm looking for in this official whatsapp FAQ's https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: By the direct way due to sandbox limitation, you have control over your app, so you can only send data from your app to another app. But right now you can not send the other applications data to your as you don't have any control over that app. May be in future these apps provide an API to get this kind of data.

Comment: @Sabby check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849810/how-to-use-springboardservices-to-get-notifications-count-of-an-app-ios

Comment: @TalhaCh, Are you sure you want to use Private API. Your app will be rejected on the app store if you want to do so. If you are going to have enterprise or jailbroken device app then you can go ahead with these kinda solutions.. There is no direct way to do this right now..

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Because Whatsapp is another app. So there is no linking between them. The apple security your app can not gets any other app information.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013 there might be a possibility.

Comment: @TalhaCh this also says that you can send data from your app to share on whatsapp..not vice versa. Thats not possible by direct way..

Comment: @Sabby have a look at this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724086/check-if-app-has-a-notfication-using-private-frameworks/19738159 this is kinda what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In latest  iOS, they've loosened that up a bit. For example, the iOS programming guide now has a section on passing data between apps by having one app claim a certain URL prefix, and then having other apps reference that URL. So, perhaps you set your event app to answer "event://" URLs the same way that a web server answers for "http://" URLs.
see this document:[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

Comment: So did whatsapp have this type of feature at the moment?